# TensorFlow DatasetOpKernel symbols missing from shared library in TensorFlow 1.6.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a TensorFlow extension that uses the `DatasetOpKernel` in TensorFlow 1.6. I'm building on Ubuntu 16.04.

Weirdly, the `DatasetOpKernel` symbols are not present in the shared library in TensorFlow 1.6, though they are for TensorFlow 1.7. My plugin fails to load due to symbol not found errors related to the DatasetOpKernel and I've confirmed using nm that no DatasetOpKernel symbols are present in the TensorFlow provided shared library.

I'm using the shared library that's installed during a `pip install tensorflow==1.6.0`

The `DatasetOpKernel` is clearly part of TensorFlow 1.6 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/dataset.h#L548) so I'd like to know how to properly link to it in my extension.

Answer (score 0):

The TensorFlow 1.6 binary release does not support creating custom `DatasetOpKernel` libraries and loading them using the `tf.load_op_library()` mechanism. This support was [added in TensorFlow 1.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.7.0).

For more details of how to create a `DatasetOpKernel` library, see the [updated documentation for handling new data formats](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/extend/new_data_formats).

Comment: Thanks. I guessed this wasn't officially supported. I got some simple examples working by linking against the pyrap_internal library for TF 1.6. I haven't run any decent tests on this yet, but I won't invest too much effort into debugging any problems that come up.